Google Group Settings API Authorization Error
I am trying to setup Group Settings service, but cannot figure out where the issue is with the authorization. Below is the code that I am using to test:
import os
import internal_package
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


# read credential from vault
gsuite_service_account = internal_package.vault.get_credential(service_account="gsuite_script", json_response=True)
if gsuite_service_account is None:
    raise ValueError('gsuite_script')
user_account = gsuite_service_account['user_email']

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings']

# Load credentials for Service Account
service_account_file = os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_file, scopes=scopes, subject=user_account)

group_client = build("groupssettings", "v1", credentials=credentials)
print("GSuite service successfully configured.")

group_email = 'soc@example.com'
group_settings = group_client.groups().get(groupUniqueId=group_email).execute()

The script is using gsuite_service_account (Google Cloud service account) to impersonate user_account (Google workspace account).
There are no errors creating the group_client, but when the script executed the last GET method, it generates an authorization error:
raise exceptions.RefreshError(
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.', {'error': 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description': 'Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.'})

I have checked the following:

The 'gsuite_service_account' has been granted the the group settings scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings) in Google Workspace under API Controls.
The 'user_account' has been granted Group Admin as well as Groups for Business role in Workspace.

I am able to use the same accounts with Admin SDK v1 successfully, but not group setting API. Any idea what I might be missing?'

I'm unfamiliar with the specific service but your process and code both look good to me. I think build is not a good proxy as -- to my knowledge -- it's not invoking any methods against the groupsettings service. Does the get succeed if you validate as a/the end user email? Is Group Settings API enabled in the Project?

I tried your code this morning and it works for me, so I'm unable to repro your issue.

I am sorry, but what do you mean by "Does the get succeed if you validate as a/the end user email?"
The Group Settings API is enabled in the GCP project to which the GCP service account belongs.
Would you be able to share what group specific permissions you had enabled for both the service accounts (GCP and impersonated workspace account)?

You're validating your code as a Service Account with authority delegated by your user (user_email). You could authenticate as that user or a suitable proxy and then use gcloud auth application-default login to convert the user's credentials into an Application Default Credentials identity (~/.config/gcloud/application-default-credentials.json). Saves the loop through a Service Account.

Alternatively make the call directly using APIs Explorer and Groups: get and click "Try it" (on the right).

Your code works for me (albeit without the secret manager)
main.py:
import os

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

project_id = os.getenv("PROJECT")
service_account_file = os.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")

user_account = os.getenv("USER_EMAIL") # me@my-domain.com
group_account = os.getenv("GROUP_EMAIL") # foo@my-domain.com

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings"]

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    service_account_file,
    scopes=scopes,
    subject=user_account,)


group_client = build("groupssettings", "v1", credentials=credentials)
print("GSuite service successfully configured.")

group_settings = group_client.groups().get(groupUniqueId=group_account).execute()
print(group_settings)

I already had a domain-wide delegated service account and added the apps.groups.settings scope per your question:
https://admin.google.com/ac/owl/domainwidedelegation
I used https://groups.google.com to create a Group (foo) and then set GROUP_EMAIL to foo@my-domain.com.
Then:
PROJECT="..." # Project that owns the domain-wide delegated account
ACCOUNT="..." # Name of the domain-wide delegated account

EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud services enable groupssettings.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL}

# Arbitrary role that it's in the Project's IAM binding
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser

Ran the code and yields:
{
    "kind": "groupsSettings#groups",
    "email": "foo@my-domain.com",
    "name": "foo",
    ...
}


Thank you for explaining. I had a domain wide delegated account as well, but it didn't have the group settings scope. I was adding the scope under third party apps as the service account was also configured as an app. I added the correct scope under domain wide delegation settings and then it worked. Although I noticed that it doesn't work right away. Not sure how long it takes for permissions to take effect, for me it did not work when I tested it right away but it worked the next morning.

I'm pleased to hear it. Permissions changes, service dis-/enablements etc aren't immediate but are usually promptly (<1 minute)
